# OpenGL doesn't render textures

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, mesh

Yesterday my OpenGL Classes have started, and me and my classmates downloaded a project made by my teacher as a sample project to learn from, on their pc it worked perfectly but all I'm seeing is white, the objects are white and the ground is white, on other classmates their pc's the objects are rendered correctly.

Does anyone know why it won't render the textures on my pc?

I've tried a few things such as, turning my Intel Graphics card off and running it on my Nvidia card, and i've tried to turn my Nvidia card off to run it on my Intel but neither worked.

My Nvidia card is a Nvidia Geforce 710M which supports OpenGL 4.5, and I have OpenGL version 4.5.

I'm not getting any errors in the code.

I'am able to see shadows I've just tried a different project and only saw shadows, the rest was all white, as it was with the first project.

Comment: Do you have the images in the right folder?

Comment: Yes the images are in the 'res' folder and they're loaded from their aswell.

Comment: Try capturing in a GPU frame debugger (eg. CodeXL), and see if the textures are present. This will let you know whether the textures are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-installed the required libraries again, then rebooted my pc and it worked :D thank you for all your help.